# oracle NUMBER to hive

Tags: oracle, hadoop, oracle11g, hive

oracle DB is storing values as NUMBER, which from my understanding is max precision and scale.  However hive documentation states that if you set DECIMAL with no precision or scale you will get DECIMAL(10,0) [doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-decimal).  What would the correct HIVE datatype be to accommodate ORACLE NUMBER.

Answer (score 1):

Since Oracle allows any precision/scale for a NUMBER datatype, safest is to store it as Hive STRING, to avoid any kind of data loss.
depending on actual data/or it's usage, downstream can convert it to needed datatype.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/bigdata/bda45/BDSUG/copy2bda.htm#BIGUG76750):

> NUMBER:
>
> INT when the scale is 0 and the precision is less than 10
>
> BIGINT when the scale is 0 and the precision is less than 19
>
> DECIMAL when the scale is greater than 0 or the precision is greater
>   than 19

Comment: the issue is when it's set to NUMBER you have no way of knowing  scale and precision as it stores the value as is...  So would one be forced to use DECIMAL(38,0)?  if this is done, 7.123 will not be stored correctly as we've set it to 0...Without combing through the data to see what the values look like what is the most suitable?  it seems as though DECIMAL(38,0) would be the safest.

Comment: the answer only addresses if the NUMBER datatype in Oracle has a scale and precision.  I am asking what is best to use when the creator of the table defined the column with NUMBER, setting no precision or scale. this is helpful but not exactly an answer to the question